# read two integers from same line in perl

Tags: perl, input

I am newbie in Perl. How do I read two integers given on same line as input in Perl?
For example:

```
$n=<>;$k=<>;
print $n + ";" + $k
```

Input is:

```
2 3
```

Output comes as:

```
2
```

Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't be performing arithmetic on a semicolon character.

Comment: `my ($n, $k) = split ' ', <>`

Comment: If you give numbers on a single line `$n=<>` will read both numbers into `$n` since `<>` (in scalar context) by default reads a line at a time.

Comment: The concatenation operator in Perl is `.`.

Comment: Also works the `my ($n,$k)=<>=~/\d+/g;`

Answer (score 1):

The `<>` operator reads one record per iteration. Records are typically newline delimited (`\n`).  That being the case, the easiest solution is to read one line as a record, and split on space:

```
chomp(my $line = <>);
my ($n, $k) = split " ", $line;
print "$n;$k\n";
```

The simple single space as a `split` delimiter is special-cased within `split` to drop leading whitespace and treat the split pattern as `/\s+/`, which is often exactly what you would want in such situations (a little default tolerance for arbitrary amounts of whitespace).

If you prefer being stricter about the format of the input, such that the split only happens if a single space character is used as the split delimiter, change your split to this:

```
my ($n, $k) = split / /, $line;
```

You can read `split`'s documentation by typing `perldoc -f split` at the command prompt on a system that has Perl installed. If you are new to Perl I also recommend spending 20 minutes to read `perldoc perlintro`. Though it doesn't explicitly discuss `split` it is a good starting point toward gaining familiarity with the language.

Your example code also was treating the `+` operator as a concatenation operator. That's an easy mistake to make, since that's precisely what it does when handed strings in many other languages. But with Perl, the concatenation operator is `.` (dot).  You can read about Perl's operators in `perldoc perlop`.

Therefore, the following are approximately equal:

```
print $n . ';' . $k . "\n";
print "$n;$k\n";
```